# Using build.exe to compile application against __cdecl symbol dll

Tags: c++, dll

I am trying to compile application which is linked to a third party DLL
compiled with __cdecl default calling convention. The header file does not
have explicit __cdecl definitions for the symbols and since the default
build.exe calling convention is __stdcall there is a conflict. The /Gz option
is added by default to the compiler options and adding

USER_C_FLAGS=$(USER_C_FLAGS) /Gd to the sources file results in a error
stating incompatible options.

My question is how to tell the build.exe tool to not use the /Gz as default
compilation option?

PS: Using the WinDDK 7600.16385.1 build environment

Comment: Add __cdecl to the corresponding declarations in the header file?

Comment: I don't have the source code for DLL

Comment: @CMouse - but you and not need have source code for DLL - you have header file - and you need add explicit `__cdecl` here to function definitions. or change default calling from `__stdcall` to `__cdecl` in your project

Comment: I tried changing the calling convention but it doesn't make any difference, still the entry point is not found for the dll

Comment: @CMouse: Where can I find Build.exe?